# как получить id равный значению в строке Djano

Tags: sql, django, объекты, model-view

Как получить во view с помощью Model.objects.get

То есть

```
`n = Model.objects.get(получить id который присвоен строке "Nmae")`
```

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение
`Model.objects.get(Name='name').id`

Comment: Будьте готовы к Model. DoesNotExist

Comment: Да, уже столкнулся с проблемой(( теперь при парсинге я получаю ошибку    `ValueError: Cannot assign "4": "Articles.SupplierId" must be a "Suppliers" instance.`